# Disable alpha blending in JavaFX GraphicsContext

Tags: java, javafx

I've got a JavaFX Canvas on which the user can draw (somewhat like MS Paint).
Now I'm trying to add the option to draw with a fixed level of opacity, meaning that no matter how often the same area is drawn on, the transparency of that area should remain the same. Right now it gets more opaque every time a line intersects itself as you would expect.
I've tried different blending modes and effects but I can't get it to work.
Is there a way to disable aplha blending altogether?

edit:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineCap;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DrawingTest extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(1000,1000);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        
        canvas.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            gc.setStroke(Color.rgb(0,0,0,0.2));
            gc.setLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
            gc.setLineWidth(10);
            gc.beginPath();
            gc.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            gc.stroke();
        });
        
        canvas.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            gc.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());  
            gc.stroke();
            gc.closePath();
            gc.beginPath();
            gc.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
        });
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();        
    }
}
```

Comment: _I've tried different blending modes and effects_ don't see that in your example ...

Comment: I removed them from this example because none of them worked and adding eveything I tried so far would've made it extremely hard to read.

Comment: Is drawing connected lines on mouse operations all the drawing you need to do on the canvas or is this just a simplified example for the question?  I ask because, if it is only drawing lines on mouse interactions, then a specific solution for that case might be created, but if there is other drawing involved, then perhaps a more general solution might need to be contemplated.

Comment: Using opaque black, the default stroke paint, seems to work.

Comment: At the moment it is only mouse interactions but a general solution would be even better in case something pops up in the future

Comment: What happens with `gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK)`?

Comment: The same, except Color.Black is 100% opaticy. Limiting it with adjustments to global alpha seems to have the same effect shwon in my example.